# What should my iOS app identifier be to work with my provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, testflight

I'm trying to use Testflight to upload an IPA to my app testers, but it's failing with the following error:

> Invalid IPA: The keychain-access-group in in the embedded.mobileprovision and your binary don't match.

I'm confused, because I think my settings are pretty standard and I have another app that I can build and distribute just fine (note: with a second developer account but in the same instance of Xcode).

Here are my settings:

- My app id that I created in the Provisioning Portal is `com.bubblefoundry.Clear`. Naturally it's then prefixed with the numeric identifier Apple assigns.
- I created an ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile with the app id and the desired devices. I downloaded it into Xcode.
- The product name is `Clear` in Xcode.
- The bundle name under the target's 'Summary' tab is `com.bubblefoundry.Clear`, where Clear is in light grey and filled-in automatically by Xcode. While I can add text before or after `Clear`, I can't delete it. The name under the 'Info' tab is `com.bubblefoundry.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}`.
- In the code signing build settings for both the project and the target, both Debug and Release are set to the iPhone Developer under the Automatic Profile Selector. I thought I might need to set Release to my distribution profile, but I didn't do this in the other, working project.

I can Archive my app just fine. Then in the organizer I can tell it to distribute it for ad-hoc development and then choose to re-sign it with the distribution provisioning profile I created earlier. No errors are reported. Likewise I can connect my iPhone and Run the app on the phone without problems. It only when I try to upload the IPA using Testflight.app that I'm told that the file is invalid.

Because it mentions `embedded.mobileprovision`, I figured I'd poke into the IPA and examine the file. Here's the relevant data (minus unique info):

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AppIDName</key>
    <string>Project Clear</string>
    <key>ApplicationIdentifierPrefix</key>
    <array>
        <string>app-id</string>
    </array>
    <key>CreationDate</key>
    <date>2013-01-11T17:44:51Z</date>
    <key>DeveloperCertificates</key>
    <array>
        <data>
      my-certificate
        </data>
    </array>
    <key>Entitlements</key>
    <dict>
        <key>application-identifier</key>
        <string>app-id.com.bubblefoundry.Clear</string>
        <key>get-task-allow</key>
        <false/>
        <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
        <array>
            <string>app-id.*</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>ExpirationDate</key>
    <date>2013-10-07T17:44:51Z</date>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Project Clear Testers</string>
    <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
    <array>
        <string>device1</string>
        <string>device2</string>
        <string>device3</string>
        <string>device4</string>
        <string>device5</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamIdentifier</key>
    <array>
        <string>app-id</string>
    </array>
    <key>TeamName</key>
    <string>Bubble Foundry</string>
    <key>TimeToLive</key>
    <integer>269</integer>
    <key>UUID</key>
    <string>uuid</string>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Looking at this, just about everything looks consistent with what I've set earlier. The only thought is that the `AppIDName` is `Project Clear`, not `Clear`. Is this the source of the problem? Or maybe `keychain-access-groups` should be `app-id.com.bubblefoundry.Clear`, not `app-id.*`?

Answer (score 1):

In this case your app id should be `com.bubblefoundry.Clear`.

If you created your provisioning profile like:

```
com.bubblefoundry.*
```

You can use this provisioning profile with various  Id's like.

```
com.bubblefoundry.Clear
com.bubblefoundry.my
com.bubblefoundry.Clear.newApp
com.bubblefoundry.testApp
com.bubblefoundry.yoyo
```

You can change the app Id in indo.plist

replace `com.bubblefoundry.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}.` with required Id like: `com.bubblefoundry.myTestApp`.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately changing the bundle id to `com.bubblefoundry.Clear` didn't help.

Comment: As for my provisioning profile, it is not a wildcard one: it's associated with app id `com.bubblefoundry.Clear`

Comment: Please delete the keychain certificate and provisioning profile-->add it again-->make a clean and build

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help.